# GroupBy on a partition then count in Opensearch: Group By on multiple fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I have the following data

```
{
  "companyID" : "amz",
  "companyType" : "ret",
  "employeeID" : "ty-5a62fd78e8d20ad"
},
{
  "companyID" : "amz",
  "companyType" : "ret",
  "employeeID" : "ay-5a62fd78e8d20ad"
},
{
  "companyID" : "mic",
  "companyType" : "cse",
  "employeeID" : "by-5a62fd78e8d20ad"
},
{
  "companyID" : "ggl",
  "companyType" : "cse",
  "employeeID" : "ply-5a62fd78e8d20ad"
},
{
  "companyID" : "ggl",
  "companyType" : "cse",
  "employeeID" : "wfly-5a62ad"
}
```

I want the following result. basically combination of values like this `mic-cse`,`ggl-cse`,`amz-ret` .

```
"agg_by_company_type" : {
 "buckets" : [
 {
    "key" : "ret",
     "doc_count" : 1
 },
 {
   "key" : "cse",
    "doc_count" : 2
 }
]
```

How do I do it?

I have tried the following aggregations:

```
"agg_by_companyID_topHits": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "companyID.keyword",
    "size": 100000, 
    "min_doc_count": 1,
    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
    "show_term_doc_count_error": true,
    "order": {
        "_key": "asc"
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
      "agg_by_companyType" : {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1, 
            "_source": {
                "includes": ["companyType"]
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

But this just gives me first groupBy of company id now on top of that data I want count of company type.
this is the response I get

```
"agg_by_companyID_topHits" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "amz",
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "agg_by_companytype" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : 0.0,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "my-index",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "uytuygjuhg",
              "_score" : 0.0,
              "_source" : {
                "companyType" : "ret"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key" : "mic",
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "agg_by_companytype" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 1,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : 0.0,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "my-index",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "uytuygjuhg",
              "_score" : 0.0,
              "_source" : {
                "companyType" : "cse"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key" : "ggl",
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "agg_by_companytype" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : 0.0,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "my-index",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "uytuygjuhg",
              "_score" : 0.0,
              "_source" : {
                "companyType" : "ret"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

If it were spark, it would be simple to partition by companyID, group it and then group by companyType and count to get the desired result but not sure how to do it in ES.

**Important Note:** I am working with Opensearch.
Possible solution for this in elastic search [multi-terms-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/7.12/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html)
is not available in versions before v7.12.

So wondering how it was done before this feature in ES.

We came across this issue because AWS migrated from ES to Opensearch.

Comment: Didn't get your expected o/p, you want the count of `companyType` coreect me if i am wrong? in this case your output should be ```"agg_by_company_type" : {
 "buckets" : [
 {
    "key" : "ret",
     "doc_count" : 2
 },
 {
   "key" : "cse",
    "doc_count" : 3
 }
]```

Comment: @amit Nope, I don't want the count of company type alone, I want combination of company type with company id. For example for type `cse` I don't want to count `ggl` twice. so for cse count will be 2 and not 3.

Answer (score 1):

use `multi_terms` agg [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html)

```
GET /products/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "genres_and_products": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [{
          "field": "companyID" 
        }, {
          "field": "companyType"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for missing information. I have updated the question. Your solution works in ES v7.12+ . 
But not in Opensearch https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch/issues/1629 . 

Which is what we had to use after AWS migrated their service from ES to Opensearch.

Answer (score 0):

can you use script in terms agg ,like this:

```
GET b1/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['companyID'].value+doc['companyType'].value",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```